# setting a javascript variable with an if statement -- should the 'var = x' be inside or outside the IF?

Tags: javascript, var

This may be a basic question but I'm having difficulty finding an answer.

You want to set var B based on var A

would you do

```
var B = if(A == "red"){"hot"}else{"cool"}
```

I don't think this works.

I guess you could do

```
if(A == "red"){var B = "hot"}else{var B = "cool"}
```

This doesn't seem particularly elegant. I mean I would prefer something that starts with var b = .... just for clarity's sake.

Comment: Firstly, your syntax for testing variable A is wrong, secondly there is the ternary operator for doing what you are after

Comment: why using var for A? and why assigning to it `=` instead of comparing it `==` ?

Comment: Are you checking to see if A is equal to "red"  (==) or are you assigning A to be "red" (=)?

Comment: **Try it out!** It'll throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I made some edits. Had a brain fart here ... yeah I mean the '==' comparison operator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

perfect use for a ternary

```
var B = (A ==="red") ? "hot":"cool";
```

Ternary expressions will always return the first value if true, the second value if not.  Great for one-off if/else statements, but if you get into more nested conditions, be sure to use the traditional if/else blocks for readability.

Comment: It can be better if you remove useless parenthesis

Comment: @AliMovahedi if it can improve readability, it is never useless

Comment: @AliMovahedi that comes down to a matter of preference.  The parens add readability imo.  YMMV

Answer (score 6):

While you could use an if statement for this, you would probably be best off using the ternary operator. In the example you describe, you'd set it up as:

```
var B = A === "red" ? "hot" : "cool";
```

The ternary operator in general works as follows:

```
someBooleanExpression ? resultIfSomeBooleanExpressionIsTrue : resultIfSomeBooleanExpressionIsFalse;
```

Also note the use of `===` to check comparison, rather than a single `=`, which is assignment. `==` could also be used, but might end up being less accurate

Comment: It would be better to use the `===` to avoid true if A is 1 or (boolean)true so that there is no type conversion.

Answer (score 5):

Initialize your variables first, then compare using if statement and assign new values where necessary

```
var a = "red";
var b;
if(a=="red"){
    b="hot";
}
else{
    b="cold";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your core you are declaring an initializing a to `"red"` which is truthy so the else clause will never be used. In JavaScript it's an if-**statement** not an if-**expression** as in say F#. That means you are not initializing B.

What you are probably looking for is

```
var B = A ==="red" ? "hot" : "cool"
```

That is to say use the **conditional** operator (*) to initialize B to `"hot"` if A is a string that equals `"red"` otherwise to `"cool"`

(*) The operator is sometimes imprecisely called the [ternary operator or more mistakenly the tertiary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/18/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary.aspx). It isn't so bad to call it the ternary operator as long as there's never added another ternary operator, at which point it would be ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

```
var A = "blue";
var B = (A == "red") ? "hot" : "cool";
```

**Second option**

```
var A = "blue";
var B = ""; // Or simply: var B;
if (A == "red") B = "hot"; else B = "cool";
```

Comment: You would need to define A or it will give you an A is not defined error

Comment: The OP is comparing it so I assumed it's already defined, but your suggestion would help in quick testing, I'll edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to CoffeeScript (which compiles to JavaScript). Then you can do:

```
B = if A == "red" then "hot" else "cool"
```

Everything in CoffeeScript is an expression! So you can assign the value of a switch statement to a variable too:

```
B = switch A
    when "red" then "hot"
    when "blue" then "cool"
    else "medium"
```

I know, I know, nobody uses CoffeeScript anymore. But it's still superior.