# IF ELSE statement to set variable value

Tags: if-statement, variables

I am creating a site where clients can construct a price quote.
I have used Tabulator to show the data in a table.
The Tabulator data is in its own .JS file "buildTabulator.js", while the Quote scripts are in another .JS file "quote.js".

I am able to extract the data and get it mostly doing what I want so far.

But, when I try to create an IF ELSE statement in the quote.js file to determine which price should be displayed based on the unit of measure (UOM) of the item, it will not work correctly. It always shows the EACH or EA price of the item which is in the IF part of the IF ELSE statement.

More specifically, if the user adds an item to the quote that is sold by the EACH it should show one price, but if they choose an item that is sold by the CASE it should display a different price.

Please see the attached screenshots and code below and advise if you can...
I am hoping this is something simple that a noob like me has missed by mistake.

First screenshot is showing the code in VSC.

Second screenshot is showing an example in the console log of the browser. This example is using an item that is sold by the CASE and should show the case price of the item but instead shows a "-" because the EACH price of this item is a dash since its not sold by the each.
In the log it shows CS for CASE which is correct but the "-" should actually be 0.2937 which is shown in the table above the console.

Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide or any questions you may have.
Thank you so much in advance!!

---

### CODE FROM "buildTabulator.js"

```
cellClick: function (e, cell) {
        globalThis.itemImage =
          "imgsQuote/" + cell.getRow().getData().IMAGE + ".png";
        globalThis.itemCode = cell.getRow().getData().CODE;
        globalThis.itemDescription = cell.getRow().getData().DESCRIPTION;
        globalThis.itemBx = cell.getRow().getData().BX;
        globalThis.itemCs = cell.getRow().getData().CS;
        globalThis.itemUom = cell.getRow().getData().UOM;
        globalThis.itemCost = cell.getRow().getData().COST;
        globalThis.itemBox = cell.getRow().getData().BOX;
        globalThis.itemHalf = cell.getRow().getData().HALF;
        globalThis.itemLess = cell.getRow().getData().LESS;
        globalThis.itemCase = cell.getRow().getData().CASE;
        globalThis.itemBxWt = cell.getRow().getData().BXWT;
        globalThis.itemCsWt = cell.getRow().getData().CSWT;
        // globalToLocal();
        setItemPrice();
      },
```

---

### CODE FROM "quote.js"

```
function setItemPrice() {
   console.log(globalThis.itemUom);
   var itemPrice;
   if ((globalThis.itemUom = "EA")) {
      itemPrice = globalThis.itemBox;
   } else {
      itemPrice = globalThis.itemCase;
   }
   console.log(itemPrice);
}
```

[image: FIRST IMAGE (CODE)]

[image: SECOND IMAGE (BROWSER)]

Answer (score 0):

after another 3 hours or so of searching I found an answer that works:

[setting variable with ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971801/setting-a-javascript-variable-with-an-if-statement-should-the-var-x-be-in)