# Why this code is incorrect in javaScript? JS experts please explain

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, conditional-statements, expression

```
var x = 10;


var b = if(x>5){return true};

console.log(b);
```

I'm not getting why this is incorrect and will give an error.

Comment: Related: [setting a javascript variable with an if statement -- should the 'var = x' be inside or outside the IF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31971801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution

```
var x = 10;

var b =  x>5? true:false
# if the condition (x>5) is true. 
# will execute the first return(true) 
# or else the second return will execute (false) 


console.log(b) #Output= true
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of a variable initializer stipulates that it must be an **expression**. An `if` statement is not an expression.

You can write

```
var b = (x > 5) ? true : undefined;
```

(or whatever you want `b` to be when `x` is not greater than 5). That `? :` expression *is* an expression, so it works as the initializer part of the declaration.